# Looking for a tool that merges pdf files

Tags: pdf

Lets say that I have 10 PDF-Files and I want to merge them in a specific order into a single one. Is there a good tool for achieving that?

Thanks in advance...

Edit:
No Webtools

Answer (score 2):

I use https://github.com/jeromerobert/pdfarranger for merging and slitting PDF files.
What I would like to highlight:

- it is an open source app
- clean interface
- portable version
- written in python

Windows version is here https://github.com/jeromerobert/pdfarranger/releases

Answer (score 1):

`poppler-utils`'s `pdfunite` is a command line tool that works for example on Linux (most likely on Windows, too).

Answer (score 1):

**[PDFtk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFtk)** is a command-line utility (CLI) for manipulating PDF files.

It's cross-plattform with many GUI extensions.

Also available in [Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdftk). Install via:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Merging from two PDFs, e.g. pages 2, 5, 6, 9 from first, pages 6, 7, 15, 19 from second:

```
pdftk A=first.pdf B=second.pdf cat A2 A5 A6 A9 B6 B7 B15 B19 output final.pdf
```

Watch the [video demo](https://youtu.be/dBTQI-V3Hsw) by Linux Foundation.
See [related question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/926920/1020048).